# Почему не работает код(односвязным списком)?

Tags: c++

компилятор выдает 15 ошибок

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    const int maxSize = 100;
    struct Travelers
    {
        int ticket_code;
        char lastname[maxSize];
        int numberofthings;
        int luggage_weight;
        Travelers* Next;
    };
    Travelers* Head;
     
    void TravelersInput(int& ticket_code,char lastname[maxSize], int& numbeofthings,int& luggage_weight)
    {
        cout << "Enter tour ticket code" << endl;;
        cin >> ticket_code;
        cout << "Enter your Lastname:" << endl;
        cin.get();
        cin.get(lastname, sizeof(lastname));
        cout << "Enter number of things:" << endl;
        cin >> numbeofthings;
        cout << "Enter your luggage weight:"<<endl;
        cin >> luggage_weight;
        cout << endl;
    }
     
    void PrintTravelers(Travelers* Head)
    {
        Travelers* j = Head;
        while (j != NULL);
        {
            cout << "Travelers: " << j->ticket_code<< ";" << j->lastname<< ";" << j->numberofthings<< ";" << j->luggage_weight<< ";";
            j = j->Next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
     
    Travelers* TravelersSearch(Travelers* Head, int numberofthings)
    {
        Travelers* p = Head; 
        while (p != NULL) 
        {
            if (p->numberofthings == numberofthings) 
                break; 
            p = p->Next;
        }
        return p;
    }
     
     
    void DeleteTravelers(Travelers*& pbeg, Travelers* pos)
    {
        if (pbeg == NULL || pos == NULL)
            return; 
        if (pos == pbeg)
        {
            pbeg = pbeg->Next;
            delete pos;
        }
        else
        {
            Travelers* prev = pbeg;
            while (prev != NULL && prev->Next != pos)
                prev = prev->Next;
            if (prev != NULL)
            {
                prev->Next = pos->Next;
                delete pos;
            }
        }
    }
     
    void Travelers(Travelers*& pbeg)
    {
        Travelers* p;
        while (pbeg != NULL)
        {
            p = pbeg;
            pbeg = pbeg->Next;
            delete p;
        }
    }
     
    int main()
    {
        int ticket_code;
        char lastname[maxSize]= { '\0' };
        int numberofthings;
        int luggage_weight;
     
        Travelers* Head = nullptr;
        int n;
     
        cout << "Number of Travelers = ";
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            TravelersInput(ticket_code, lastname, numberofthings, luggage_weight);
        }
     
        cout << " deleted Travelers = ";
        cin >> luggage_weight;
        DeleteTravelers(Head, TravelersSearch(Head, luggage_weight));
        PrintTravelers(Head);
     
        FreeTravelers(Head);
     
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всего-лишь три ошибки, исправляем и работаем.

Для функции `get` меняем размер указателя на ёмкость буфера, то-есть не

```
cin.get(lastname, sizeof(lastname));
```

, а

```
cin.get(lastname, maxSize );
```

Исправляем бесконечный цикл :

```
while (j != NULL);
```

путём убирания точки с запятой (*пустой команды*)

```
while (j != NULL)
{
        cout << "Travelers: " << j->ticket_code<< ";" << j->lastname<< ";" << j->numberofthings<< ";" << j->luggage_weight<< ";";
        j = j->Next;
}
```

Переименовываем функцию с именем класса :

```
void Travelers(Travelers*& pbeg)
```

на правильное название

```
void FreeTravelers(Travelers*& pbeg)
```

Comment: почему я могу ввести только tickcket_code и last name дальше программа просто завершается?

Comment: после `get` надо очистить буфер. щас найду. кажется `cin.clear();` - но лучше спросите в другом вопросе.

Comment: `sizeof(lastname[maxSize])` — это не размер массива, а размер _элемента массива_. Хотя строго говоря, тут скорее всего UB из-за выхода за пределы массива.

Comment: И я в том-же духе. исправил. это надо в другом вопросе показать. @wololo